# How to download and use ShareCompat library

Tags: android

I need to share some text from my app to google plus and I googled and found many links saying
to use ShareCompat and i found this code sample

```
     Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(ShareActivity.this)
.setText("This site has lots of great information about Android!
  http://www.android.com")
.setType("text/plain")
.getIntent()
.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");

 startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But i want to know from where to download this ShareCompat API. Any one please can provide a link for this. Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Many thanks,
Mona

Comment: I managed to upload a file, how did you download a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ShareCompat` is part of the Android Support package, available in the Extras are of your SDK Manager.

Documentation on using `ShareCompat` can be found on the [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.html).

Comment: I have Android Support package installed in my Extras in android, but still ShareCompat is not available :(

Comment: @MunazzaKhalil: You have to add it to your project. See http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp (or, in Eclipse, try right-clicking on the project and choosing Android Tools > Add support package)

Comment: i added this library and using sharedcompat but when i run the above code on a button click it gives me error on startActivity(shareIntent) that activity is not found ?

Comment: @MunazzaKhalil: Delete the `setPacakge()` line. Do not limit you users to particular apps for sharing their text, and do not assume every Android device on the planet has Google+.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using the android SDK app that pulls all the other SDK packages/updates.

Here's the official link that describes what it is and how to get it:
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html